# Apache Superset containers report 'unhealthy' status

Tags: docker, apache-superset

I'm trying out Apache Superset on UIbuntu 22.04. I use the install from [docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/superset) as follows:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8088 --name superset apache/superset
```

After about two minutes `docker container ls` tells me that the status of the container is `unhealthy`. It is possible do `docker exec -it` into it to perform prescribed actions as setting the admin credentials, updating the database and initializing superset. After having done that I can login, connect databases and create dashboards. The logs appear to be ok. What's weird: by clicking `settings` the about info at the bottom shows 0.0.0-dev.

Trying to install [with docker-compose](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose/) does not change the situation, it does produce a lot more docker containers of which `superset_app` and `superset_worker` are both `unhealthy`.

Any idea why the containers are `unhealthy`? And which installation method is most preferred provided that I can everything up and running? Personally I prefer the first one because it results in 1 container instead of the about 6 from the second method.